# Почему std::array::front и std::array::back не являются noexcept?

Tags: c++, массивы, visual-c++, исключения

Почему [std::array::front()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/front) не помечен как `noexcept` для непустых массивов?

Почему [MSVC помечает его как noexcept](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/array#L546)? Разве это не нарушение [стандарта](https://eel.is/c++draft/array#overview-5)?

Comment: Думаю, что в VC++ примечание  **`/* strengthened */`** многое поясняет :)

Comment: Нарушения стандарта здесь нет, т.к. реализациям разрешено усиливать спецификацию исключений. [res.on.exception.handling/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/res.on.exception.handling#5): `An implementation may strengthen the exception specification for a non-virtual function by adding a non-throwing exception specification.`

Comment: Функция `front` не помечена  в стандарте `noexcept` т.к. комитет по стандартизации придерживается позиции, что функции, вызывающие неопределённое поведение на некоторых входных данных (для `front` — это пустой массив), не должны быть помечены `noexcept`. Это полезно для отладочных целей. В недрах `front` можно добавить проверку на пустой массив, и при необходимости _генерировать исключение_, не опасаясь конфликта с `noexcept`-спецификатором. См. подробности в [noexcept Prevents Library Validation](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3248.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если  `std::array` будет пустым, то `std::array::front()` (и std::array::back() тоже) вполне может генерировать исключение, но может просто вернуть значение по умолчанию, выдав при этом предупреждение. Это зависит от реализации.  В `VS`, например, он  реализован как  noexcept(другие не проверял). Реализация не может знать будет ли пустым ваш массив по ходу программы? Она может  только выдать исключение(предупреждение) для  `array<T, 0>`

Comment: В спецификации написано, что [The effect of calling front() or back() for a zero-sized array is undefined](https://eel.is/c++draft/array#zero-3). Добавил в вопрос про MSVC. Размер массива же задаётся на этапе компиляции, так что реализация знает, будет он пустым или нет.

Comment: @karmik, это не реализация знает, а компилятор

Comment: Если бы в стандарте было `noexcept`, а компилятор этого не делал - было бы плохо и нарушение стандарта. Ужесточение же нарушением стандарта, строго говоря, не является?